# What can I do with broken (burnt) rooms?

Tags: theme-hospital

If you leave a machine without maintenance or endure heavy earthquakes, it's likely going to explode at some point, leaving you with a burnt room that you can't sell or rebuild.

Is there something to do with it, some way to pay to repair/rebuild it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing. The room is never going to be usable again, and the space in which the room was placed will be permanently unusable.