# What's a good strategy to prevent machines from exploding?

Tags: theme-hospital

In order to ensure machines don't explode, of course it's necessary to regularly check them and page handymen to maintain them. However, earthquakes are sometimes so violent that it's simply not possible to save all the machines, resulting in [destroyed rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182644/what-can-i-do-with-broken-burnt-rooms)...

What can I do to prevent explosions resulting from earthquakes?

Is it possible that putting several extinguishers into each room with a machine could stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've found on the web, so far:

**Extinguishers**

> Fire extinguishers may seem useless, but they do the same job as plants and don't need watering. They also delay the explosions of machines, therefore they are more useful in rooms.

([Source](http://www.gamesradar.com/theme-hospital/cheats/))

**Research**

> Go to your Research Department window (the one with the tubes), and increase the bar of "Improvements" to at least 70 percent. That way, you're giving almost full priority to make your machines stronger.  Suppose your inflator has strength 8. Whenever your researcher improves it, it goes up to strength 10!!

([Source](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/2202/t1582817-exploding-machines/))

**Handymen**

> Don't hesitate to hire lots (yeah, LOTS!) of handymen. At least 40 of them!! [...] not only you will notice that your machines are fixed sooner, also your hospital will be pristine! Make sure you take some time to go through your machines to see how many times were used.

([Source](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/2202/t1582817-exploding-machines/))